# Why do I get a type error related to Prisma ORM's automatically generated types when attempting to build my Next.js application in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, next.js, typeerror, prisma

My application works as expected in dev mode but fails type validation in build. I am trying to use the [types that Prisma automatically generates](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/type-safety/operating-against-partial-structures-of-model-types) from its descriptive database models.

Here is the relevant model in the Prisma schema. I'm using postgresql:

```
model Post {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  slug        String    @unique @db.VarChar(300)
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime? @updatedAt
  title       String    @db.VarChar(200)
  subheading  String?   @db.VarChar(200)
  published   Boolean   @default(false)
  publishedAt DateTime?
  editedAt    DateTime?
  author      User      @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId    Int       @default(1)
  html        String?
  category    Category  @default(NOTE)
  tags        Tag[]
  comments    Comment[]
}
```

On the `/posts` route I am attempting to pass a single post object as a property to the `Postcard` component.

`src/app/posts/page.tsx`:

```
import prisma from '@/prisma/prisma'
import type {Post} from '@prisma/client'
import Postcard from '@/components/postcard'

async function getPosts() {
  return await prisma.post.findMany()
}

export default async function Posts() {
  const posts: Post[] = await getPosts()
  if (posts) {
    let output = []
    for (const p of posts) {
      output.push(
        <Postcard post={p} />
      )
    }
    return output
  } else {
    return (
      <>[No Data]</>
    )
  }
}
```

And here is `src/components/postcard.tsx`. Note how I'm importing the same type used above with `import type {Post} from '@prisma/client'`:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import type {Post} from '@prisma/client'

export default function Postcard({post}: Post) {
if (post) {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          {post.id}
        </div>
        <div>
          <Link href={"/" + post.slug}>
            {post.title}
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div>
          {post.html}
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Below is the error thrown on build:

```
./src/app/posts/page.tsx:15:19
Type error: Type '{ post: { id: number; slug: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date | null; title: string; subheading: string | null; published: boolean; publishedAt: Date | null; editedAt: Date | null; authorId: number; html: string | null; category: Category; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { id: number; slug: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date | null; title: string; subheading: string | null; published: boolean; ... 4 more ...; category: Category; }'.
  Property 'post' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { id: number; slug: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date | null; title: string; subheading: string | null; published: boolean; ... 4 more ...; category: Category; }'.

  13 |     for (const p of posts) {
  14 |       output.push(
> 15 |         <Postcard post={p} />
     |                   ^
  16 |       )
  17 |     }
  18 |     return output
```

Comment: `Postcard({post}: {post: Post})`

Comment: Thank you! That was it. So that's how destructured object parameters work.